# chrome to disable notification sound

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to disable a notification sound for a particular URL.

How can I disable the annoying sound effect?

Answer (score 8):

If you mute the sound for a web page, it will mute all the sound for that page (not just for the notifications from that page), so the answer of changing the settings in Chrome here is not useful for muting Chrome's notification sounds.

I have found a solution for users of Windows 10.  To mute notification sounds, use the notification settings in Windows itself.

1. Go to this page and open the notification settings for Windows 10:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028678/windows-10-change-notification-settings
2. You are now in Windows 10's notification settings page.  Scroll down to "Google Chrome" and click the Chrome icon to open the notification settings
3. Toggle "Play a sound when a notification arrives" to Off
4. That's it.

I hope this helps, at least Windows 10 users.

Answer (score 2):

To save time you can disable all sounds for the page with Chrome settings by following this path:

Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced -> Content settings -> Sound -> Muted -> Add (input your URL)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It generalizes to all Chrome users as of 2020/04/09

Comment: The "Content settings" option is not there. I did manage to mute the page on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5 mini), but the notifications still make sound.

Comment: In my version of Chrome (86.0.4240.75) the sound settings were in "privacy and security" -> "site settings" -> "additional content settings". Or (easier!) search for "sound" in the "search settings" box!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [Chrono Dowload Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jceIz.png), which can disable it's own notifications.  Click the cogs for settings and choose [Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SIcy.png) and turn off "Play sound when ..."